# Write a large NSDictionary to file crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, plist, writetofile

When I use `[dic writeToFile:path atomically:YES];` I received a crash like this：

```
0   CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation) + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 56
2   Foundation  _NSErrnoMessage (in Foundation) + 0
3   CoreFoundation  __CFSafelyReallocate (in CoreFoundation) + 136
4   CoreFoundation  __CFDataGrow (in CoreFoundation) + 412
5   CoreFoundation  CFDataReplaceBytes (in CoreFoundation) + 440
6   CoreFoundation  _plistAppendCharacters (in CoreFoundation) + 180
7   CoreFoundation  _CFAppendXML0 (in CoreFoundation) + 2228
8   CoreFoundation  _CFAppendXML0 (in CoreFoundation) + 2720
9   CoreFoundation  _CFAppendXML0 (in CoreFoundation) + 2720
10  CoreFoundation  _CFPropertyListCreateXMLData (in CoreFoundation) + 216
11  CoreFoundation  CFPropertyListCreateData (in CoreFoundation) + 152
12  Foundation  +[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:] (in Foundation) + 48
13  Foundation  -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) writeToFile:atomically:] (in Foundation) + 180
```

I think the NSDictionary contains more items ,failed when malloc memory.
How to write a large dictionary to file? or other best way? 
So can someone help me please what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have more logs ?

Comment: Try to set an exception breakpoint and force the crash again to give us more information.

Comment: I tried many times on simulator and my iPhone ,but I can't  force the crash again. This crash log report by analysis SDK and most on ios 11.x and iPhone plus.